# VBA Excel workbook locked while trying to protect it using vba with wrong syntax

Tags: excel, vba

I used the wrong syntax of protect workbook method in vba and now I'm not able to unprotect it either manually or by vba.

method I used

```
ActiveWorkbook.Protect Password = "a"
```

instead of

```
ActiveWorkbook.Protect Password:= "a"
```

I'm attaching a sample workbook to explain the problem better.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/j9gbs653c3ekljq/vbaprotect-unprotect.xlsm?dl=0

Regards,
Sushant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is to change the filetype from ".xlsm" to ".zip".
Then you open the zip file and find "xl/workbook.xml". Open the file, locate and delete the workbookProtection section of the xml file. This would look like this.

```
<workbookProtection lockStructure="1" workbookSpinCount="100000" workbookSaltValue="toN4kCMV7rKY3ILzsrftPA==" workbookHashValue="3fup/MHNNDJdbhPyerFBJtGVu1ymCUX4Gq1vSRd6x7nUQey6orASofK+Fp/kaNjErr5VMZekaGG5m+Q9bpHPDg==" workbookAlgorithmName="SHA-512"/>
```

(Just delete everything from < to /> of the section)

Save the workbook.xlm file in the zip folder.
Close the zip and change the filetype back to ".xlsm" and your workbook protection is gone.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much. I got my workbook back. I had spent 1 week in creating this workbook with most of the sheets hidden. I thought I had lost all my work. Thank you so much again!

Comment: No worries, workbook protection ain't secure at all since it just a simple XML setting protecting it. Glad i could help :)

Answer (score 0):

If you used

```
ActiveWorkbook.Protect Password = "a"
```

to protect your workbook then your password is `False` because  `Password` is an empty variable and therefore it is not `a` so `Password = "a"` would evaluate to `False`.

So

```
ActiveWorkbook.Unprotect Password:="False"
```

should unprotect your workbook as well as using the "wrong" syntax to unprotect it

```
ActiveWorkbook.Unprotect Password = "a"
```

---

Alternative is running this line of code in VBA in your workbook.

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Value(11) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Value(11)
```

Due to a bug in Excel it will kick out the protection completely without the need to know the password.